# Format interval as "YMD" format with the format being a parameter in the function

Tags: vba, function, date

The following is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function StudyDuration(ByVal Start As Date, Format As String, Optional ByVal Graduation As Date, Optional ByVal Expected As Date) As String

  Dim TillGraduation As Integer

  StudyDuration = Graduation Or Expected - Start
  TillGraduation = DateDiff("ymd", Date, Expected)

  If Graduation = 0 And Expected = 0 Then Graduation = Date

  Range("B1").Value = Start
  Range("B2").Value = Graduation
  Range("B3").Value = Expected
  Range("B4").Value = StudyDuration
  Range("B5").Value = TillGraduation


  If Graduation = 0 And Expected > Start Then

  StudyDuration = Expected - Start And TillGraduation =     DateDiff("ymd", Date, Expected)

  MsgBox ("Study Length" & " is" & Range("B4").Value & vbNewLine & Range("B5") & "till Graduate")

  End If
End Function
```

However, the cell B1 keeps showing the date 1/7/1900. Can anyone tell me how should I correct it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would help to show exactly how you're calling this function.

Comment: Don't name a parameter after a function #upsetCompiler

Comment: This line looks odd StudyDuration = Expected - Start And TillGraduation =     DateDiff("ymd", Date, Expected)

Comment: `Function`s are suppose to do calculations and return you a result, and not to change Range values unless the Range is one of the parameters. Also refer to [MSDN `DateDiff` usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datediff-function).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that functions are not allowed to modify cell values. A function is only supposed to return a value that will set the value for the cell that is called from.

If you want to modify cell values, then you should look at using a Sub instead.

BTW, your function makes no use of the Format parameter.